# Python decorator with threading / threading behaviour

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I needed to display a waiting message for the user while a function is doing its work (in this case specifically, waiting for a response from Google's speech-to-text service). I therefore used threading for this task, and it works well. Later it occured to me this could be useful in the future, so decided to turn this into a decorator, which is something I haven't done before. After many tries (including an ill-fated attempt at using a class for it), this is what I came up with:

```
def loading_decorator(function):
    def loading_wrapper(*function_args, active=True):
        def loading_animation(speed=4, loading_text='Processing... '):
            for symbol in cycle(r'-\|/-\|/'):
                if not active:
                    print('\b' * (len(loading_text) + 1))
                    break
                print('\r', f'{loading_text}', symbol, sep='', end='')
                sleep(1 / speed)
        loading_thread = threading.Thread(target=loading_animation)
        loading_thread.start()
        result = function(*function_args)
        active = False
        loading_thread.join()
        return result
    return loading_wrapper
```

... and this is the function I've decorated:

```
@loading_decorator
def process_speech(audio):
    return r.recognize_google(audio, language=LANGUAGE)
```

I was happy to see it worked as intended. I have two questions however:

1. I initially had `time.sleep(0.5)` in the code in place of `loading_thread.join()`. I put it in because without sleeping, the result would be returned before the cleanup activated by `active = False` happened, and the loading text remained in the window. I found this surprising, can this behaviour be explained easily? I guess I assumed (wrongly) the change to `active` would somehow nudge the loading thread to stop looping. Is there a reason the main thread is given priority here? Is this something obvious to more knowledgeable people?

Only later I thought using `loading_thread.join()` instead of sleeping might be more proper. I'm not feeling confident here, since this is my first foray into both threading and decorators (except for some very basic ones). Which brings me to my second, more general question:

2. Does the code look alright to you, or could it be improved somehow? I'm happy it works, but some insight from the experienced folk would be great.

Comment: It's not "priority", but the thread that is running will keep on running.  Threading in Python is somewhat of a sham; only one thread at a time is allowed to run Python code, so the main thread will continue to run until it does some I/O or some other blocking operation.

Comment: 1. Most of the time the animation thread `sleep`s so the main thread can continue before the animation thread recognizes that it should stop. 2. You should handle the case that `function` raises an exception. A try-finally-block helps here to ensure that the cleanup is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems allright + you have some suggestions already in comments.

Here's my take on the problem:

I'd "reverse" the roles and let the function run inside `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the printing code in the main thread. That way I'd get rid-off the variable `active`.

Also I'm using `functools.wraps` + I use decorator parameters to make it more nice.

```py
import concurrent.futures
from functools import wraps
from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep


def loading_decorator(speed=0.2, loading_text="Processing... "):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                future = executor.submit(f, *args, **kwargs)
                for ch in cycle(r"-\|/-\|/"):
                    print("\r" + loading_text + ch, end="", flush=True)
                    if future.done():
                        print()
                        return future.result()

                    sleep(speed)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@loading_decorator(speed=0.1)
def some_long_task():
    sleep(5)
    return "result"


x = some_long_task()
print(x)
```